Java and React: send file to server
I would send some image to server from react:
    static async uploadImg(img) {
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', img, img.name)
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        console.log(img);
        const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/image', data,
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
                'Authorization': token
            }
        })

        return response.data;
    }

but when I do it, I get from java server shoved in image:

,
There's code from java code, where server get image:
    @Operation(description = "Upload Image")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> uploadImg(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            Principal principal
    ) throws IOException {
        if(Objects.requireNonNull(file.getContentType()).startsWith("image")) {
            Long idImage = imageService.uploadImage(file, principal).getId();
            log.info("Upload Image by user " + principal.getName() + ": " + file.getName() + " with id: " + idImage);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(idImage);
        } else {
            log.info("Bad request by user " + principal.getName() + ": " + file.getName());
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
    }

With other links I don't get CORS-error, but with it I do it
I would like just send image from react app to java spring server
